# Create a custom component for lightswitch

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I will have to use lightswitch for a project.

I know that we can create some UserControl, and specify "Custom usercontrol" when selecting the way to display the information.

But, is it possible to create a generic userControl, which can be selected the same way as "Grid" or "List"?

Because I've some usercontrol libraries and I would like to use some user control of it in a generic manner?

(e.g. have my custom usercontrol which display a grid, and still have the possibility to select which column will be displayed without having to create a new usercontrol for each datatype)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference for custom controls is [lightswitchhelpwebsite](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/tagid/2/Custom-Controls.aspx).

You should to know that create a 'specific' custom control is easy but create a generic custom control is quite dificult. Then, it is not possible to write here document, code and samples to make a generic custom control.

Michael Washington (Microsoft) says that their book explains how to do this: [Michael Washington's book](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Market/Books/CreatingVisualStudioLightSwitchCustomControls.aspx) can help to you.

Another interesting resource is [Visual Studio LightSwitch Training Kit Jul.2011](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23746)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to write a Custom Control Extension. You can find out more details on how to do this through the MSDN help page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674919.aspx